# Umbraco - postbacks caching problemm

Tags: umbraco

I'm having a problem with a page I'm developing in umbraco. I'm fairly new to it so would really appreciate some guidance.

the problem seems to be connected to the way umbraco caches pages.

what i have is a stockist locator map (a map of Australia in my case).

from this page, the user can select a region to see stockists within that area.

i have a big fat search button along with some checkboxes for the user to choose what region they want to search in.

when i check say 'Sydney' and hit my search button, all is well. it returns the results i would expect.

*but*... if i go and click the search button straight away (again) - then the search results disappear.

its almost like umbraco is doing some weird caching thing. I've tried fiddling with the caching settings within the developer area (i.e. 'Cache Period'), but haven't spotted any consistent patterns which shed light on the problem.

oh, another thing - its not executing the page load and pageInit events (when retrieving from the cache).

Answer (score 0):

So when you submit you control without selecting anything, you get empty result. Can this be, that is the logic of a control itself? As I see, it just gives empty result for empty search query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some sample code to demonstrate your implementation?

I've done plenty of Umbraco sites and have rarely found that Umbraco interrupts the normal ASP .Net page lifecycle so I'd be more inclined to guess you have a fault in your code.

Have you tried disabling your custom caching completely to ensure that the issue does not relate to your code?

Does your cache have a param dependency that is being cleared or anything?